# Bad notification for startForeground with PendingIntent.getService?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

From time to time I get a:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But only on Android 4.3. On Android Kitkat or Lollipop it works as intended. The issue only persists when I use PendingIntent.getService like this:

```
Intent rewindIntent = new Intent(AudioPlayerService.this, AudioPlayerService.class);
PendingIntent rewindPI = PendingIntent.getService(
    AudioPlayerService.this, 0, rewindIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_fast_rewind_grey600_36dp, null, rewindPI);
```

But when I instead use

```
Intent i = new Intent("pause");
PendingIntent pauseActionPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.addAction(R.drawable.av_pause_dark, "Pause", pauseActionPI);
```

it works on all versions of android. Why is that the case? what am I doing wrong?

You can see the complete source code [here](https://github.com/Ph1b/MaterialAudiobookPlayer/blob/v1.4.0/audiobook/src/main/java/de/ph1b/audiobook/service/AudioPlayerService.java#L274) and a previous working version [here](https://github.com/Ph1b/MaterialAudiobookPlayer/blob/v1.3.0/audiobook/src/main/java/de/ph1b/audiobook/service/AudioPlayerService.java#L290)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after looking like forever, I found the solution. The problem is, that if you set an action like

```
Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.av_pause_dark, null, pendingIntent);
```

it will crash on Android version 4.3, but will work fine on other versions.

The point is, you have to define the shown text. If you want to have not text (like me), you have to set it to

```
Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.av_pause_dark, "", pendingIntent);
```

**So the trick is to set `""` instead of `null`.**

Comment: Please have text, for accessibility if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Builder to set the icon and also double check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification).

Required notification contents

```
A Notification object must contain the following:

 - A small icon, set by setSmallIcon() 
 - A title, set by setContentTitle()
 - Detail text, set by setContentText()
```

Comment: I use the builder to do that. Also this crash never occured on my own devices, just for some (Like Galaxy s3)